# Meteor subscription won't set checkbox if app is refreshed

Tags: meteor

I'm running into an issue with Meteor subscription not setting checkbox "checked" after refresh. Basically, if I have Meteor running and change the JS, the app works as expected (pulls data from Meteor.user() and sets checkbox accordingly). However, if I refresh the app all my checkboxes are set to false.  I don't see why that should happen, any ideas?

My subscription looks as follows:

Server-side

```
Meteor.publish("user-preferences", function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
            {fields: {'notification': 1}});
    } else {
        this.ready();
    }
});
```

Client-side:

```
Meteor.subscribe("user-preferences", function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        var notification = Meteor.user().notification;
        // Check to see if notification and systems exists; if not, default to TRUE
        if (notification) {
            Session.set('aNotificationPreference', notification.hasOwnProperty('a') ? notification.a : true);
        }
        else {
            Session.set('aNotificationPreference', true);
        }
    }
    else {
        // TRUE too if no user yet
        Session.set('aNotificationPreference', true);
    }
});
```

This is the helper that will look up the session variable to make things reactive:

```
Template.preferences.helpers({
    isChecked: function() {
        console.log('#### PREF INITIAL: ' + Session.get("aNotificationPreference"));
        var pref = Session.get("aNotificationPreference");
        if (typeof pref === 'undefined') {
            Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                pref = Session.get("aNotificationPreference");
                console.log('#### PREF IN TIMEOUT: ' + pref);
                return pref ? 'checked' : false;
            }, 1250);
        }
        else {
            console.log('#### PREF in ELSE: ' + pref);
            return pref ? 'checked' : false;
        }
    }
});
```

Finally, this is the HTML checkbox field:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-theme="b" name="aNotificationSwitch" id="aNotificationSwitch" data-mini="true" checked={{isChecked}}>
```

This is based of the [Blaze documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected) on this specifically and other posts I found.

I know the issue is in the helper but I'm not sure how to address it.  The logs on failure show as follows:

```
Application Cache Checking event (index):1
Application Cache NoUpdate event (index):1
#### PREF INITIAL: undefined index.js?8b2a648142fb63b940f4fb04771d18f25b5bf173:63
Connected to Meteor Server. index.js?8b2a648142fb63b940f4fb04771d18f25b5bf173:37
#### PREF INITIAL: true index.js?8b2a648142fb63b940f4fb04771d18f25b5bf173:63
#### PREF in ELSE: true index.js?8b2a648142fb63b940f4fb04771d18f25b5bf173:73
Connected to Meteor Server. index.js?8b2a648142fb63b940f4fb04771d18f25b5bf173:37
#### PREF IN TIMEOUT: true
```

Comment: seems like there could be a number of places where things go wrong. Have you added some `console.log` statements along the way, e.g., in the `onReady` function of the `subscribe`? Have you checked the value of the session variable in the console?

Comment: Yes, everything works as far as getting the value, but what I see is that the Session variable is undefined in the helper when I see this fail so I guess there's a race condition with that and the subscription.  How can I force the helper wait till that value is set before setting the template?  Moreover, why isn't it reactive after the session variable is set because it does get set once the subscription returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to set the flipswitch with jQueryMobile by doing the following on my panel's open event in the `Template.body.events`:

```
'panelbeforeopen #mypanel': function() {
    //Refresh flipswitches prior to opening sidepanel otherwise they default to disabled
    $("#aNotificationSwitch").flipswitch("enable").flipswitch("refresh");
    $("#bNotificationSwitch").flipswitch("enable").flipswitch("refresh");
    $("#cNotificationSwitch").flipswitch("enable").flipswitch("refresh");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Meteor yet.

But I would change the JavaScript you have for:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

  Template.preferences.helpers({
    isChecked: function() { return Meteor.user().notification ? 'checked' : false; }
  });

  Template.preferences.events({
    'click #aNotificationSwitch': function(event){
      var checked = event.target.checked; // true or false
      Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, $set: {notification: checked});
    }
  });
}
```

It's different from your approach though. With this way you don't need to use session variables.

Allowing to update users:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function(userId, user){
    return user._id == userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: Still suffers from the same problem. You have to have a subscription in place for your notification object off the Meteor.user() call and so if the subscription hasn't been filled that evaluation will be undefined at the time the template is being rendered. It seems you can't change the value of a checkbox `checked` attr after it's rendered because as you can see from my logs the helper gets called again and the value is `TRUE` .

Comment: I forgot to add you have to allow user updates, do you know how to do that? it seems a problem of allow more than pub/sub

Comment: I'm sorry what does that have to do with the issue? I'm not having any issues updating the user record. That works great! The problem is as I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your first comment redaction